# React Redux onDeleteClick isNot Function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table to implemetnt table in react. My problem is onDeleteClick method.
In the example below, this function works correctly.

```
const StorehouseListTest = ({ storehouses, onDeleteClick }) => (
  <table className="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th />
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {storehouses.map(storehouse => {
        return (
          <tr key={storehouse.id}>
            <td>
              <Link to={"/skladiste/" + storehouse.slug}>{storehouse.storehouse_name}</Link>
            </td>
            <td>
            <button
                className="btn btn-outline-danger"
                onClick={() => onDeleteClick(storehouse)}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

However, in the code below I use react-bootstrap-table-next when I want to include onDeleteClick in function actionsLink button and I get the error that "onDeleteClick is not a function" when press button.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';

const { SearchBar } = Search;

function actionsLink(cell, row) {
  return (
    <div>
            <div className="btn-group">
              <a
                href={"/skladiste/" + row.slug}
                className="btn btn-md btn-outline-success icon-btn borderless"
              >
                <i className="ion ion-md-search"></i>
              </a>          
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-danger"
                onClick={() => this.onDeleteClick(row.slug)}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>

  );
}

const columns =  [
    {
        dataField: "id",
        text: "ID"
    },
    {
        dataField: "storehouse_name",
        text: "Storehouse name"
    },
    {
        dataField: "available",
        text: "Available"
    },
    {
        dataField: "id",
        text: "Actions"
        formatter: actionsLink
    }
]

const StorehouseList = ({ storehouses, onDeleteClick }) => (
    <>
        <ToolkitProvider
        keyField="id"
        data={ storehouses } 
        columns={ columns } 
        search
        >
        {props => (
            <div>
                <SearchBar { ...props.searchProps } />
                <hr />
                <BootstrapTable
                    {...props.baseProps}
                    keyField="id"
                    bootstrap4
                    striped
                    hover
                    pagination={paginationFactory()}
                />
            </div>
            )
        }
        </ToolkitProvider>
    </>
);

StorehouseList.propTypes = {
  storehouses: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onDeleteClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default StorehouseList;
```

**Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this problem?**

Comment: hello, it is obvious, the **actionsLink** function doesn't have a defined function inside it called **onDeleteClick**, so you cannot make this call **this.onDeleteClick(row.slug)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `actionsLink` you cannot use `this.onDeleteClick` because it is only passed to `StorehouseList`.

It looks like `react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit` has the option to pass extra data to the formatter, so you can use this to pass `onDeleteClick` to your `actionsLink` by including it as extra data for your column formatter:

- https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columnformatextradata-any
- https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columnformatter-function

Note that you'll need to define columns inside of `StorehouseList` in order to use the `onDeleteClick` that's passed to it:

```
const StorehouseList = ({ storehouses, onDeleteClick }) => {
    const columns =  [
        ...
        {
            dataField: "id",
            text: "Actions"
            formatter: actionsLink,
            formatExtraData: { onDeleteClick },
        }
    ];

    return (
        <ToolkitProvider
            ...
    )
]
```

Then in `actionsLink` use the fourth argument to get `formatExtraData.onDeleteClick`:

```
function actionsLink(cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) {
    ...
        <button
            ...
            onClick={() => formatExtraData.onDeleteClick(row.slug)}
            ...
}
```